# Purpose of class extends MovieClip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have just started learning AS3 and my school has provided some Class files with the basic structure already written. Here is an example:

```
package {
//Add in your import statements here
//...

public class MathsQuiz extends MovieClip
{
    //Add in your class variables here
    //...

    public function MathsQuiz()
    {

    }

    public function startGame()
    {

        //Get the game loop to execute
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
    }

    public function update(evt:Event)
    {
        //This is the game loop

        //Handle user input

        //Handle game logic

        //Handle display

    }       
}//end class
```

}//end package

My Question is, what does "extends MovieClip" actually do?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extends` keyword allows a class to inherit any publicly-accessible or protected member variables and functions of a base class (in this case, `MovieClip`).

In this example, this means that `MathsQuiz`, on top of any functionality you may add, will also function as a `MovieClip`. On a basic level, this means that it is a display object that can be added to the display list and moved around via its `x` and `y` properties.

For a more in-depth understanding, do some research on [OOP Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

The [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) class inherits from the following classes: [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html), [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html), [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html), [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) (can be added to the display list, moved around via its x and y properties as Marcela said), and [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html), but unlike the Sprite object, a MovieClip object is [Dynamic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html) (A dynamic class defines an object that can be altered at run time by adding or changing properties and methods. A class that is not dynamic, such as the String class, is a sealed class. You cannot add properties or methods to a sealed class at run time.) and has a timeline.
If your class doesn't use timeline (looks like that is the case), you can extends Sprite and will have the same results and better performance. If you want a dynamic class you can just use the dynamic attribute when you declare a class.